# How to find the version of a Crystal Report rpt file?

Tags: crystal-reports, version

I have a Crystal Report file from an old version (unfortunately I don't know and cannot find out easily which version was used) and I need to do changes in that RPT file. I would like to find out which version is the RPT file so I can install the proper version of the editor.

If I install the all new and latest version, when I save the RPT file it tells me that the original file was from an old version (does not specify which) and that the save will upgrade it to the latest format, thus previous version of the application will not be able to use it. Not much help there.

I also checked all around Crystal Report to find a "Properties" or "Information" window, without success.

Is there a way to know which version a RPT file belongs to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SAP Crystal Reports: Report / Performance Information / Report Definition 
should show File Format Schema

Comment: I don't understand this answer/solution. I think, those are menu items in visual studio. Is this right? Can someone please give a short instruction how I get the version.

Comment: No it isn't the answer for Visual Studio, but SAP Crystal Reports

Answer (score 2):

Is the version showed at the path mentioned in the above post the version of the file or the version of the software installed in the system? The file might have been develpoed in a lower version of Crystal Report tool and due to the upward compatibility it is opening up properly and showing the version of the tool and not the version of the file on which it is developed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture of the information by going to Report / Performance Information / Report Definition[image]

This shows it is version 10.2